# Notification on long-running query or deadlock in SQL Server 2008 R2?

Tags: query, deadlock

I'd like to know if there is a way to send a notification on deadlock? If so what queries would be required. I understand that SQL Server takes care of deadlocks, I simply would like information on the queries involved.

I found the following to determine long-running queries:

```
SELECT 
    creation_time
    ,last_execution_time
    ,total_physical_reads
    ,total_logical_reads
    ,total_logical_writes
    , execution_count
    , total_worker_time
    , total_elapsed_time
    , total_elapsed_time / execution_count avg_elapsed_time
    ,SUBSTRING(st.text, (qs.statement_start_offset/2) + 1,
    ((CASE statement_end_offset
        WHEN -1 THEN DATALENGTH(st.text)
        ELSE qs.statement_end_offset END
    - qs.statement_start_offset)/2) + 1) AS statement_text
FROM sys.dm_exec_query_stats AS qs
    CROSS APPLY sys.dm_exec_sql_text(qs.sql_handle) st  
where total_elapsed_time >= 300000000 --5 min
ORDER BY total_elapsed_time / execution_count DESC;
```

I'd like to know if the above is the right way to go, or is there a better way to determine if any query takes longer than a specific interval say 5 min as shown?

Thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

With SQL 2008 there is a new feature that you can use for deadlocks and long running queires: [extended events](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb630354%28v=SQL.100%29.aspx). Extended events are low level objects and consume much lesser resources than other methods like profiling/tracing, alerts, etc...

For using extended events with `deadlocks` check out this [post by Jonathan Kehayias](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/deadlock/65658/), a SQL server MVP.

For using extended events to find `long running queries`, check out this detailed [post by Pinal Dave](http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2010/03/29/sql-server-introduction-to-extended-events-finding-long-running-queries/), another SQL server MVP.

Answer (score 10):

You can configure alerts for both of these with SQL Agent.  Create a new alert and select type "SQL Server performance condition alert"

For long running queries, choose Object "MSSQL$InstanceName:Transactions" and Counter: Longest Transaction Running Time. Configure the values, and the alert notification options, and you're good to go.

For deadlocks, the Object is "MSSQL$InstanceName:Locks" and the Counter is "Number of Deadlocks/sec"

If you want more fine grained control of the deadlock notification, check this out:
http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/Administration/3243/

Comment: I attempted to setup the alert as you suggested, however the job will only run if I have steps defined. Is there a way to setup the alert without defining job steps?

Answer (score 4):

I would favour @StanleyJohns suggestion if you have SQL2008. Extended events are worth familiarising yourself with as a diagnostic tool and Jonathon's [An XEvent a Day](http://www.sqlskills.com/blogs/jonathan/category/Extended-Events.aspx#p25) series is a great place to start.

An alternative for deadlocks is to [enable trace flags 1204 and 1222](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178104.aspx), which dump deadlock information to the SQL error log. Enable both, so you get the information in two differing formats, which can make it easier to understand complex deadlock chains.